# AutoCompleteExtender in EditItemTemplate in DetailsView having issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, autocompleteextender

I have 2 identical AutoCompleteExtender's - one is in the Insert mode of my DetailsView, which is the default mode, and one is in the Edit mode. There is also another DetailsView, which only shows when a Checkbox is ticked (and the page posts back), which also hides the previous one.

When the mode is Insert, there are no issues at all, even when ticking the checkbox to hide the DetailsView with the AutoCompleteExtender in and show the other one (which has no AJAX controls btw). But when the mode changes to Edit, and the user ticks the checkbox to change to the other details view (with no ajax), I get this error:

> Extender control 'autoNom' is not a
>   registered extender control. Extender
>   controls must be registered using
>   RegisterExtenderControl() before
>   calling RegisterScriptDescriptors().
>       Parameter name: extenderControl

Any ideas guys?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any chance you could post the mark up you are describing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the other DetailsView. Try deleting the extender for the edit mode and and configure it again. Because it looks like there is something with the Ajax config in the edit more. Make sure about the namings.